# Dynamic command handler with shared and seperate commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I am setting up a command handler for multiple channels (Twitch). At the moment I have all the commands divided in folders user specific and the generic ones. Accessing them by using a `map()`. I would like each user/channel to have access to only their folder and the generic one. The map key is name in a .js file.

So what would be the best way to do it? Ive tried mapping over the generic folder and the folder that matches the user name on login, but I am not aware of a way to change the "command" in `client.commands.set(key, value)` so it would be `client.(nameChannel).set(key, value)`. Then I would be able to probably assign the default and user specific folder to the map.

Also `fs.dirReadSync` lists all of the .js files in a folder and sub folder. How do I access all of them at once in require? Wildcards don't seem to work so do I need to list them like shown below?

I want to be able to add more later and not hardcode them one-by-one if possible.

```
//hardcode example.
var moduleA = require( "./module-a.js" );
var moduleB = require( "../../module-b.js" );
var moduleC = require( "/my-library/module-c.js" );
```

The piece of code below is still a work in progress. What I like to achieve:

- exclude channel specific commands from being called from other channels.
- know if/what the standard or recommended approach is.
- how to `require()` all .js from the `readDir` sync in one require.

```
client.commands = new Map();
 //add commands property/method to client instance. A map to iterate over.
 const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync("./commands").filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));
 //reads file system and filter .js files only. returns an array of those items.
 for (const file of commandFiles) {
     const command = require(`./commands/${file}`); //this only grabs the results in commands itself can't use wildcards..
     //sets a new item in the collection.
     //Key of map is command name.
     client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

//input validation etc here
//check command

     try {
         client.commands.get(commandFromMessage).execute(channel, commandFromMessage, argument);
     } catch (error) {
         console.error(error);
     }
```

pastebin of the folder tree: https://pastebin.com/XNJt98Ha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set string names as your keys in regular objects.

```
const channelSpecificCommands = new Map();
const channelFolder= fs.readdirSync(`./commands/${channelSpecificDir}`);

for(const file in channelFolder) {
    const commandFromFile = require(`./commands/{${channelSpecificDir}/${file}`)
    channelSpecificCommands.set(commandFromFile.name, commandFromFile);
}

client[channelSpecificDir] = channelSpecificCommands;
```

For your second question - you should be using `.json` files instead of `.js` for this. You can load json files with `JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('myjsonfile.json', 'utf8'))` to get the data without any issues that come with dynamic module resolution.

Comment: Thanks for the json suggestion. the examples I am following used .js files but I saw a lot of json in real projects. Will have to look into it though because I am unsure how/when to use the parse. 

As for the code am I to set the strings the whole time and loop? Because channelSpecific Dir is undefined at this.

Comment: Also the extra bracket next to $ is that a typo or a function/use that I haven't seen before?